# Showing my domain instead of my ip with apache

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost, apache-2.4, domain

**What I have**

I have a domain configured to point to my server.

When I go to my domain, let's say:

```
example.com
```

it redirects me to:

```
http://104.286.131.72/mysitefolder/index.php?
```

And of course, it shows me the right site.

I have apache for this, and a file called `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysitefolder/
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**What I want**

When I go to my domain:

```
example.com
```

it redirects me to:

```
http://example.com/index.php?
```

And showing me the same site.

**How can I do that?**

> Update1

Tried to change the second block to @imvikasmunjal answer and I git this:

```
The requested URL /mysitefolder/index.php was not found on this server.
```

The `/var/log/apache2/access.log` file says:

```
190.126.199.244 - - [25/Apr/2016:01:43:43 -0400] "GET /mysitefolder/index.php? HTTP/1.1" 404 521 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
```

> Update2

I have an `.htaccess`like this:

```
#Domain: 104.286.131.72
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/mysitefolder/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
....
```

Comment: In the first virtual host, Try providing ServerName default & reload Apache and also do you have any .htaccess redirects in /var/www/mysitefolder/ ?

Comment: This is most likely configured in whatever web app you try to run on that machine.

Comment: @serverliving.com thank you, I updated my question with the htaccess file. I created a `Hello world` html site and it worked with your suggestions but my main site doesn't work so definitely is something with the .htaccess file but still not sure what exactly it is.

Comment: I think you don't require this rule RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/mysitefolder/] since your DocumentRoot is already pointing to /var/www/mysitefolder/ . You can try commenting this rule

Comment: I completely delete this file and generated again with my app as @Sven suggested. It works now! the rule looks like this now: `E=REWRITEBASE:/]`. @serverliving.com your comments give me the answer, you should put them together in an answer so I can accept it and more people could take benefit of that.

Comment: @serverliving.com I edited your answer just to show the complete solution that worked for me.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't require this ->RewriteRule . -[E=REWRITEBASE:/mysitefolder/]

since your DocumentRoot is already pointing to /var/www/mysitefolder/ . You can try commenting this rule or replace it with RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the domain with IP address.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysitefolder/
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

instead of this use:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysitefolder/
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In place of `*` add the domain name.

Comment: Added that and now I get a 404 `The requested URL /mysitefolder/index.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: error_log will give you more idea, What's the error in the log for that 404 error. Your first configuration looks correct to me. Also are you using apache 2.4 ?.

Comment: @serverliving.com thank you, I updated my answer with that information. Still getting the error.